# Combining Purim meal with Friday night meal

Tags: purim, meal-seudah, erev-shabbat

Can you have a joint purim seuda and friday night meal if you started before skiah on the Friday. What are the implications - re continuing a meal into shabbos re benching, lighting candles, davening, not eating once you light candles until kiddush etc etc.

Comment: See the Minhag of the Meiri in Kesuvos 7a or b don't rem offhand

Answer (score 3):

Rav Eliezer Melamed writes [here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/05-16-15/):

> [T]here is a custom to combine the Purim meal with the first Shabbat meal on Friday night. Some great Torah authorities follow this custom, while others recommend doing so only *be-di’avad*. In order to follow this custom, one must pray *Minĥa* and then begin the meal while it is still Purim. Then, around a half-hour before *shki’a*, one should accept Shabbat by lighting the Shabbat candles, place a covering over the bread, and recite *kiddush* over wine. Since one has already recited the *berakha* over wine (*Ha-gafen*) during the Purim meal, one should omit that *berakha* in *kiddush*. After *kiddush*, one continues the meal, making sure to eat a *keveitza* of bread, or at least a *kezayit*, for the Shabbat meal. At the end of the meal, one recites *Retzei Ve-haĥalitzenu* in *Birkat Ha-mazon*, adding *Al Ha-nisim* in the *Ha-Raĥaman* (“May the Merciful One”) section at the end of the prayer. After the meal, one prays *Ma’ariv*.

Comment: Huh. Why is this bediavad? Sounds like a great idea, compared to what most of us do: Try to recover in time for Shabbos.

Comment: @MichoelR my guess [is this](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.5?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.271.21&lang2=he)

Comment: @MichoelR מצוה להמנע מלקבוע סעודה שנהוג בה בחול מט' שעות ולמעלה:

Comment: @JoelK who said they're starting their meal so late?

Comment: @robev Is that just talking about a start time? How does that fit with the point of this 'mitzva'?

Comment: @robev Most people who follow this custom probably don’t start so early. If they do, (and notwithstanding DoubleAA’s point above) they are still left with a couple of minor issues: Kabbalistically one should not make kiddush before arvit, and there is also a debate as to whether one says al hanissim in birchat hamazon

Comment: @JoelK They could break for Arvit in the middle of the meal (if they are sufficiently sober)

Comment: @DoubleAA True. Although if they want to go to shul that raises other issues of חברים שהיו יושבים לאכול ויצאו

Comment: @JoelK Solution for non-covid years: have a lot of male guests

Comment: What about kabbalat shabbat?

Comment: See [here](https://ohr.edu/9245#_edn10) for a lot of relevant sources for why this is complicated and best to be avoided.

Comment: Why does no one do this for shaloshdes and yom tov meal when yom tov is sat night? I guess the only good time is eighth day pesach and second day rosh hashana. Or Friday Shavuot evening if you spent most of the day sleeping. Truthfully I don't get what all the hubbub is about with a seudat purim on Friday. We manage two and three day yom tov all the time, no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

As couple of points are addressed by **HaRav Chaim Bleier** in his Chukei Chaim series on Parshas Tzav 5779 [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B900wzePoK4beFprNm10X2xjYXZWQ2Q1UWFheWVhWC01LU9j/view?usp=sharing)

He writes there:

> **If one began his Purim seudoh during the day and wants to continue it into the night as his Shabbos seudoh, he must stop eating and make Kiddush close to bein hashmoshos before continuing since the chiyuv of Kiddush then takes effect ([שו"ע סי' רע"א ס"ד](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))**

As far as bensching he mentions:

> ### **Bentching - Retzei and Al HaNissim**
>
> 47. **Did not eat bread at night**. If one made a ‘poreis mapoh’ seudoh but did not eat after tzeis, some say he should say Retzei in bentching, but he should not repeat it if he forgets ([שו"ע סי' רע"א ס"ו](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) [ומ"ב סקכ"ט](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.6?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.271.29&lang2=bi) ו[ל](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.6?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.271.30&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en)); Others say he should not say Retzei (רמ"א שם).
> 48. **Ate at night**. If one began his seudoh by day, continued into Shabbos night, and ate at night, all poskim agree he should say Retzei (מ"ב שם).
> 49. **Al Hanisim**. If one says Retzei in bentching, he should not say Al Hanisim since that would be contradictory. Since Al Hanisim is not as crucial, he should only say Retzei ([מ"ב סי' תרצ"ה סקט"ו](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.695.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Comment: This has a lot of info, perhaps too much for a quotation, and amazingly it doesn't answer anything asked. I guess maybe a bit about bentching. But it doesn't answer if you can do this, or anything about candlelighting and davening.

Comment: @DoubleAA - does it not go through what one should do if he wants to combine his Purim Seudo with his Shabbos meal?

Comment: no it goes through various issues of kiddush and motzi when combining his purim meal with his shabbos meal. It doesn't answer if you can do this, or anything about candlelighting and davening. That's what the question asked.

Comment: @DoubleAA - this any better?